# formulario con carga de archivos y inputs en .net core y angular

Tags: sql, .net, netcore

Estoy teniendo problemas en crear un formulario en el cual el usuario rellene un formulario con nombre, apellido y subir un arhivo pdf(en .net core). Busque tutoriales y no se como plantear el problema. De momento logre realizar la carga de archivos pero no puedo agregar a la tabla el nombre y el apellido o no se bien como hacerlo. Si alguien me puede ayudar si se puede hacer en una misma tabla o tengo que crear una tabla persona y otra tabla archivo y relacionarla o como debería enfrentar el problema. Les dejo mi código a continuación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a continuacion les dejo el controlador:

```
namespace BackendApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class FileManagerController : Controller
    {
        private readonly string AppDirectory = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot");
        private static List<FileRecord> fileDB = new List<FileRecord>();

        // -------------------- CONTEXT CLASS DECLARATION ------------------------

        private readonly AppDbContext _authContext;
        public FileManagerController (AppDbContext appDbContext)
        {
            _authContext = appDbContext;
        }


        // -------------------- SEND FILES METHOD POST ------------------------

        [HttpPost]
        [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync([FromForm] FileModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                FileRecord file = await SaveFileAsync(model.MyFile);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FilePath))
                {
                    file.AltText = model.AltText;
                    file.Description = model.Description;
                    //Save to Inmemory object
                    //fileDB.Add(file);
                    //Save to SQL Server DB
                    SaveToDB(file);
                    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                }
                else
                    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(ex.Message),
                };
            }
        }

        private async Task<FileRecord> SaveFileAsync(IFormFile myFile)
        {
            FileRecord file = new FileRecord();
            if (myFile != null)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(AppDirectory))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(AppDirectory);

                var fileName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(myFile.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(AppDirectory, fileName);

                file.Id = fileDB.Count()+1;
                file.FilePath = path;
                file.FileName = fileName;
                file.FileFormat = Path.GetExtension(myFile.FileName);
                file.ContentType = myFile.ContentType;
                file.AltText = file.AltText;
                file.Description = file.Description;

                using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await myFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }

                return file;
            }
            return file;
        }

        private void SaveToDB(FileRecord record)
        {
            if (record == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(record)}");

            FileData fileData = new FileData();
            fileData.FilePath = record.FilePath;
            fileData.FileName = record.FileName;
            fileData.FileExtension = record.FileFormat;
            fileData.MimeType = record.ContentType;

            _authContext.FileDatas.Add(fileData);
            _authContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        // // -------------------- GET ALL FILES  ------------------------

        [HttpGet("getallfiles")]
        public List<FileRecord> GetAllFiles()
        {
            //getting data from inmemory obj
            //return fileDB;
            //getting data from SQL DB
            return _authContext.FileDatas.Select(n => new FileRecord
            {
                Id = n.Id,
                ContentType = n.MimeType,
                FileFormat = n.FileExtension,
                FileName = n.FileName,
                FilePath = n.FilePath
            }).ToList();
        }


        //// -------------------- GET FILES BY ID  ------------------------
        [HttpGet("getallfiles/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile(int id)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(AppDirectory))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(AppDirectory);

            //getting file from inmemory obj
            //var file = fileDB?.Where(n => n.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            //getting file from DB
            var file = _authContext.FileDatas.Where(n => n.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

            var path = Path.Combine(AppDirectory, file?.FilePath);

            var memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            var contentType = "APPLICATION/octet-stream";
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

            return File(memory, contentType, fileName);
        }







    }





}
```

necesito que cuando una persona se postule  a un trabajo pueda cargar su imagen con su nombre y apellido.

Comment: Hola tomsi, bienvenido, te sugiero que elimines las imagenes y agregues el código como texto, de esa manera evitarás recibir votos negativos y recibirás respuestas, de paso puedes hacer el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: "no puedo agregar a la tabla el nombre y el apellido" porque? queproblemas tuviste? donde te trabaste? que probaste?

Comment: la verdad es que me tira error todo.. hasta al querer agregar las propiedades(nombre,apellido,email) no se a cual de los 3 modelos agregarlo.